# Is there a way to use Word Interop or VBA to get the original text of a paragraph (or any range) that contains revisions?

Tags: vba, interop, ms-word, revision

Seems like accessing the revision ranges only gives me the updated text. I'd like to see the text as it originally was so I can create a report that says something like "Change  to ."

Answer (score 1):

I believe that once you get a range object, you can access the revisions made to that range via Range.Revisions.

then you'll have to enum the revisions and look at the TYPE of revision to determine what kind of change it was.

If you want the original version, you may have to open a second copy of the document, select your range, then REJECT all the revisions in that range, read the value of the range and through that copy of the doc away.

Comment: The problem is accesing the ORIGINAL text !

Answer (score 0):

Rejecting the revision will change

Range.text

to the original text.

You can then undo changes to set it back to revised text.